# F#: System.Drawing.Graphics namespace not defined

Tags: f#, mono

I've got a brand new and very minimal F# project; I'm on OSX, using Mono and Paket and Emacs. In this project, I'm trying to use the rich and wonderful world of `System.Drawing`.

I can do this just fine:

```
open System.Drawing
```

Great, no problems. Also this:

```
open System.Drawing.Drawing2D
```

Super duper. But this:

```
open System.Drawing.Graphics
```

Tells me the namespace is not defined.

I'm new to the F# neighborhood, so possibly I'm missing something obvious, but my understanding is that `System.Drawing.Graphics` is part of the `System.Drawing` assembly, and thus the DLL, that `System.Drawing` and `Drawing2D` are definitely already using perfectly happily.

Where do I even start with this?

Comment: [`System.Drawing.Graphics` is a class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx), not a namespace...

Comment: https://imgflip.com/memegenerator/Captain-Picard-Facepalm